# How to style Go errors with HTML and CSS?

Tags: go, go-templates

I would like to style Errors in my Go Web Application.

Currently I am handling errors like the following example:

```
if !ok {
    http.Error(w, "Username and/or password do not match", http.StatusForbidden)
    return
}
```

However this causes the error message to be displayed in the browser as simple text.  I would like to style my errors with HTML & CSS, but it seems bad practice to simply ignore the `http.Error` method and use:

```
TPL := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
if !ok {
    TPL.ExecuteTemplate(w, "usernamePasswordMismatch.gohtml", nil)
}
```

Can someone recommend a way to properly handle my error, with the `http.Error` method or something similar, and still style my Error page with HTML & CSS?

Comment: This is often called "message flashing". Typically what you do is have a cookie that you can push messages onto (usually with a severity, e.g. info, warning, error, etc). Then using javascript you get the messages from the cookie and clear it. For example, you could have an element `<div id="flash-messages"></div>` that, on page load, you insert messages into based on the cookie.

Comment: The more proper way is to bind the messages to your request that you can access in the template, but the cookie method is more universal.

Comment: @Jesse can you expand on your second comment?  How do you bind the messages to your request, and how do you access this in a template?  Can you provide some pseudo-code example as an answer?

Comment: Just treat it like a normal page; make a template with a replacement for your message and ignore `http.Error()`. That method is convenience for people not concerned with formatting.

Comment: simple template replacement -> https://gowebexamples.com/templates/

Comment: Ok I will go with the second method.  Thank you all.

Comment: In the second method, you should `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)` before executing the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing the template, you can manually write the http status code with [`w.WriteHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) you want returned:

```
TPL := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
if !ok {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
    TPL.ExecuteTemplate(w, "usernamePasswordMismatch.gohtml", nil)
}
```

You want to call `WriteHeader` before writing the actual data or else the `ResponseWriter` will automatically use `StatusOK` as the response:

> ```
> // If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls
> // WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @xgord Yes this addresses the question.  Cerise Limon in the comments above wrote it also.  Appreciate it.  I can't upvote because of my reputation.

Comment: @Jesse how does it not answer the question? the OP wanted to return an http error status but also render a template.

Comment: @Peter ah, so Cerise Limon did. Didn't even notice that comment. Glad you figured out your problem.